# Noach Burial Place

Tags: history, geography, cemetery-grave, noach-noah-the-man

Where was [Noach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah) buried? (or, do we know?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

R' Yehosef Schwartz, in his Tevuos HaAretz (composed in the 1840s), writes (translation from [here](http://www.jewish-history.com/Palestine/lebanon.html)):

> Twenty-five miles southeast of
>   Baal-bek is the village Sachala, where
>   the inhabitants point out a monument,
>   which they allege to mark the grave of
>   Noah. That, however, but little faith
>   can be placed in such like popular
>   legends, will appear from the fact
>   that also in the land of Armenia, in
>   the vicinity of Mount Dshudi (the
>   Ararat of Gen. 8:4), on which the ark
>   rested at the flood, they also point
>   out an alleged grave of Noah. But
>   other similar examples can be cited to
>   prove the credulity of the people in
>   giving currency to unauthenticated
>   legends.

So we probably don't really know for certain.

Comment: Wow, I would not know where to begin to look for an answer to that question